# Displaying multiple video feeds on android in a single activity

Tags: android, video, android-activity

### Hi!

I'm trying to play `multiple video streams` on a single activity but in some cases (tried on different devices) it doesn't work and throws an error (sorry for not posting it here, i can only reproduce it in the office since there is where i keep the devices..).

Also, at some cases the two disjoint VideoViews (or SurfaceViews) are treated as one view and display the same video feed.

---

I think it is all the ROM's fault and the MediaPlayer native implementation but i would surely like to hear what you all think. So please comment and help me solve this annoying issue.

Thank you!

*amir*